# Adding multiple field.ids to a React form?

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

this is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am trying to make a React form that when you select a country it comes up with different fields to fill out and then submit.

So far with my code I can only use one field.id in my form when I select Brazil as my country. How do I make it so that I can have multiple fields come up to fill in?

I have just started learning React and this is for a project. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

The link to my app is here with all of the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-example-forked-7fkgz?file=/src/Form.js

Here is my code so far(my Form.js code):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Field from "../src/Field";
import styles from "../src/styles.css";

const fields = [];

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: [
        {
          id: "first-name",
          className: "label",
          name: "first_name",
          label: "First Name",
          type: "text",
          defaultValue: "",
          isShowing: false
        },
        {
          id: "martial-status",
          name: "martial_status",
          label: "Martial Status",
          type: "text",
          defaultValue: "",
          isShowing: false
        },
        {
          id: "country",
          name: "country",
          label: "Country",
          type: "select",
          defaultValue: "Canada",
          options: [
            {
              className: "label",
              value: "Canada",
              label: "Canada"
            },

            {
              className: "label",
              value: "Brazil",
              label: "Brazil"
            }
          ],
          isShowing: true
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleFieldsChange = this.handleFieldsChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleFieldsChange(name, value) {
    if (name === "country" && value === "Brazil") {
      this.setState({
        fields: this.state.fields.map((field) =>
          field.id === "first-name" ? { ...field, isShowing: true } : field
        )
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.fields);
    return (
      <div className="pkg-settings">
        <form method="post">
          <table className="form-table">
            <tbody>
              {this.state.fields.map((fields) => (
                <Field
                  key={fields.id}
                  attr={fields}
                  handleFieldsChange={this.handleFieldsChange}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <p className="submit">
            <input
              type="submit"
              name="submit"
              id="submit"
              className="buttonbutton-primarybutton-large"
              value="Submit"
            />
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice to see you learning, great job, what you have is working! you are currently filtering your fields at the on change moment. That handleFieldsChange function is the place you have to understand what you are doing; first of all, I would rename it, because is just one field component changing being handled then what you have to think now is what you want to do when the user select the country, just try put something like this and you will be able to see more fields from the state to see what Im telling you:

```
handleFieldChange(name, value) {
if (name === "country" && value === "Brazil") {
  this.setState({
    fields: this.state.fields.map((field) =>
      { ...field, isShowing: true }
    )
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Hi guiwme5, thank you for helping me out! When I do that I get an error message in my Field.js file, saying that "this.props.handleFieldChange is not a function.  

    this.props.handleFieldsChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);

Comment: Guiwme5 it worked! I forgot to change it further down in my code so it wasn't rendering correctly! Thank you so much!!

Comment: that is because you renamed the prop too. To do that you should change the name of the prop where is being declared (inside Field) and where is being called outside => 
...........
myFunction( ) { console.log("this is being passed to the prop") };
.............
<Field handleFieldChange ={myFunction}>.

// src/Field.jsx ...
Field extends React.Component {
....find here your handleFieldsChange function and rename it to handleFieldChange (singular)

Comment: congrats! don't forget mark the question as solved!

Comment: One last question: If I want to only show certain fields for certain countries, should I change ....field to an array that lists the certain fields I want for that country???

Comment: You could create arrays of fields for each country and for each view of your form.
The initial fields in the first view is the select, the other views are brazilFields, the canadanFields and ghanaFields groups. Set your sublist of fields in arrays with all you need and check the logic for each selection:

this is an approach (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-example-forked-57xwk?file=/src/Form.js) using sublists with just the field name and then filtering with the whole info from the initialFields

Comment: Thanks guiwme5! I really appreciate all of your help!